# eBay getItem api endpoint returns "The specified item Id was not found" for existing products

Tags: javascript, ebay-api

I'm trying to fetch product information for some products on ebay using their api. But i'm running into the following response for existing products on ebay.

```
{
  total: 0,
  warnings: [
    {
      errorId: 11001,
      domain: 'API_BROWSE',
      category: 'REQUEST',
      message: 'The specified item Id was not found.',
      parameters: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
const fetchEbayProduct = async function (id, access_token) {
  const headers = {
    "X-EBAY-C-ENDUSERCTX": "contextualLocation=country%3DUS%2Czip%3D19406",
    // "X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN": access_token,
    Authorization: `bearer ${access_token}`,
    "X-EBAY-API-VERSION": "967",
  };

  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item?item_ids=v1|${id}|0`,
    { headers }
  );
  console.log(response.data);
};
fetchEbayProduct(155443592481, accessToken)
```

I tried this on multiple products and each request responded the same.